# Why I have the ActionBar under my tabs?

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

There's something I'm missing but I can't find it out. Could you help me please?

Style.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>

<style name="Theme.Styled" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar.TabView</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyCustomTabView</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@color/tab_color</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar.TabView"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_example</item>
    <item name="android:width">30dp</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">@color/tab_color</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_example</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@color/tab_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/tab_text</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTextColor</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@color/tab_color</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">0dp</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTextColor" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/tab_text</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomTabView" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

Java class:

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

comment the below line. you will get the action bar back to top.
//actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

Comment: remove that line.. what i meant is comment that line.. it will work fine without that line.. i have tried your code.

Comment: Okay now I have it on the top, but I forgot to mention that I don't want the icon in the ActionBar. Anyway thanks.